# linker error when compiling, using C++ builder from Embarcadero, LME200 ilink32.exe

Tags: linker-errors, c++builder, heap-memory

Suddenly I get an error message when trying to compile and run a program.

---

```
[ilink32 Warning] Warning: C:/lms/Profloor v5/Win32/Debug/Profloor v5.ilf: 0x00010000 / 0x13000000
[ilink32 Warning] Warning: C:/lms/Profloor v5/Win32/Debug/Profloor v5.ils: 0x0003b000 / 0x08000000
[ilink32 Warning] Warning: Error detected (LME200)
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
```

---

I have tried several things like disabling the virus scanner, change the heap settings, run it on a different computer. all fails. And the problem is there on all my projects. Updating to version `10.3` did not solve the issue.
any suggestion?

Comment: How much RAM your system have?

Answer (score 1):

**this solution works also already tested on Windows 10 Pro 64bit.**

Download LAMarker.exe need the account!: https://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30459

Direct download LAMarker.exe: https://cc.embarcadero.com/Download.aspx?id=30459

> make a backup copy of the ilink32.exe file inside the C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin folder.
>
> Open the Command Prompt as an Administrator and type the commands to
> go to the BIN folder

**Enter the command:**

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin
```

[cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8cy9.png)

**Enter the command:**

```
LAMarker.exe -M -Filink32.exe
```

[LAMarker.exe -M -Filink32.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17xzx.png)

> it will create a copy of ilink32.exe and modify it, the original will
> be renamed to ilink32.exe.old

Comment: this is really great! i got it back to work again. Thanks a lot.

Comment: does this also work for the ilink64 version?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem 3 times using Kaspersky antivirus, I solved the problem by cleaning all the *.tmp files in the temp folder,
another thing that also worked before was to increase the virtual memory and restart.

Comment: Hi, i have tried both as well. no succes. Even turning off the virusscanner did not help

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly I got the same error:

```
[ilink32 Warning] Warning: unknown heap name   : 0x08000000 / 0x08000000
[ilink32 Warning] Warning: Error detected (LME200)
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
Failed
```

**The solution for this was:**
The error occurred, when I opened the Workspace in file explorer by double-clicking on the workspace file xy.cbproj.
When I closed Embarcadero, started Embarcadero from Windows-Start and opened the Workspace by Menu-File-Open Workspace the same project compiled and linked with no problem!